# linkedin share button is getting the wrong page title

Tags: linkedin-api

We gave a list of jobs here - http://jobs.abilityprofessional.com/jobseeker/SearchResults.aspx?featured=1&runsearch=1

If you click on any job to go to the detail page and then click the linkedin share button it always comes up as the Industrial Sales Representative - Columbus, OH job instead of the actual job that you're looking at.  I've checked the og:title tag and it's correct, so I'm not sure what's going on here.  Is this possibly a linkedin cache issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your OG tag format is a bit off.  LinkedIn (and the official OG spec, for that matter:  http://ogp.me/) is looking for `<meta property="" ...>` not `<meta name="" ...>`.

See their docs here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#opengraph

Note that you will now have a cache problem, however.  They cache their content for 7 days, so the improper tags will be stuck that way for a few days for any jobs you've already tried to share.  Make sure you test with ones that you haven't attempted to share yet so they get a fresh visit from LinkedIn's crawler.

Comment: I'll give that a try but I'm not sure if that's it.  The reason is that our software powers a couple of hundred job boards like this site and we've checked a number of other sites and they all work fine.  Guess I'll have to check in a week to see if that helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn cache can be cleared by submitting the url here `https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/`